# How do I store a password that I need the true value for?

Tags: java, security, encryption

I have a password/key that I need to use in my Java program. I need to use it with an external application so 2-way encryption is not an option. My issue with 1-way encryption is that the decryption key will be laying around my code somewhere so it isn't any more secure in the end. So how do I store this password safely? I was thinking of storing it in an external file that is read in but I don't know how well this would work for deployment and such.

Comment: As far as storing passwords goes, you don't have a half-decent option, let alone a good one. In fact, all this one-way encryption thing is the result of a simple realization that a good option does not exist.

Comment: There's no easy answer to this. If the external application can be configured to use an external authentication server then you would be best off using that. In other words, your user is authenticated in a server which both your application and the external application use to authorise rather than passing passwords.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between encryption and hashing? If you create a good secure _hash_ of a password, then while collisions are a possibility, there are a lot of hash algorithms out there for which the probability of a collision is very low if not negligible. Just hash!

Comment: @fge that still does not help in this case, if the hash is good enough to send as identification it can also be stolen and used as identification.

Comment: @fge I think OP's situation is that their application needs to log in to an external application that wants a password in the clear. They want to somehow encrypt the password in their code and then decrypt it before passing it in the clear to the external application. If I've got that right (not sure of that) then a decent answer would resolve decades of academic work on security!

Comment: @sprinter That is correct. There doesn't seem to be a decent solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments says, you can not do this in a secure way.
Anything that allows you to retrieve the password will open the possibility for someone else to do it also.
What you can do is have a separate password for each installation and let the user/admin that installs the application worry about securing the password. That would allow them to store the password in a separate file or input it during application startup or whatever feels secure enough.

If the password is to an external service there is a good chance they want to have some control over the usage anyway.

If the password is to your own service you might ask yourself what your "threat-model" is. Is it really a problem if someone retrieves the password, and if it is you probably want to be able to shut down that password without affecting all users/installations.

Answer (score 0):

If you use one-way encryption, then you can only encrypt, not decrypt.

In your password file, have salted, encrypted passwords. The algorithm is:

1. New User selects password, system assigns id to the new user
2. Salted Encrypted password = `encrypt(password + id);`
3. Store salted encrypted password in file

When someone logs in, do the following:

1. receive username and password for login attempt
2. lookup id for username
3. salt and encrypt entered password as above
4. compare with file, if it matches, it's OK

Answer (score 0):

As far as storing passwords goes, you don't have a good option: a sufficiently determined person will find a way to get to your password. In fact, the development of one-way encryption is the result of a simple realization that a good option for storing recoverable passwords does not exist.

If you must communicate with an application that requires a password, and you are not willing to have the end-user provide that password each time it is needed to log in, you could use a non-portable way of encrypting small amount of text that is often available on many operating systems. The idea is to "piggyback" on some encryption done by OS, which is protected by credentials of the current user or the current network service.

For example, on Windows you could use the Current User Hive of the Windows Registry to store the password, and then read that password from your Java program. The password is stored in encrypted form, and is available only to the current user. The protection relies on users supplying their login credentials before running your program.

On Mac OS you could get similar kind of protection by storing the password in the keychain. In both cases you end up with a non-portable solution.